# Html page basic layout using div percentage (HTML 4)

Tags: css, dom, layout, html

I am newbie in web design. I have one rule that everything should be flexible. I don't understand why px are used widely in web design instead of percentage, maybe I am wrong.
I have been looking for base html layout like on the picture below for a long time, but found only examples where some magic negative margins/paddings and PX are used
I want to create such layout but using percentage without any px attribute.

I am not sure if I am right , but I hate everything tightly dependent. All examples seems not flexible for me, of course I can use media queries, but I need to get such result using percentage or whatever not tight to the screen dimension.

https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/543_html5/2_Column_Layout.png

Please, can someone provide such example HTML + CSS (HTML 4 not 5).

Comment: You can convert the templates you are finding to % values

Comment: Please provide some skeleton just div blocks and css

Answer (score 1):

try this and change/edit how ever you want

**HTML 5**

```
<header>HEADER</header>
<nav>NAV</nav><main>MAIN</main>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: teal;
}
nav {
    width: 20%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: olive;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: orange;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I need HTML example

Comment: There is no way to do this in HTML 4 ?

Comment: I believe this answer is useful in HTML4, @fheoosghalzr. The only things you should be careful of are the tags used, but you can replace them with <div> and a little CSS to make them look better.

Comment: you can still use this as it is for HTML 4

Answer (score 0):

This one is very classic, with floating and stuff:

http://codepen.io/denns/pen/LpBXBa

## HTML 4

```
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="nav">navi</div>
<div class="main">main</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

## CSS

```
.header {
  background-color: coral;
  height: 100px;
}

.nav {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 400px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.main {
  background-color: hotpink;
  height: 400px;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}

.footer {
  clear : both;
  background-color: #0ff;
  height: 100px;
}
```

But this does not solve the problems you normally have. Like "the navbar is supposed to have the same height than the content". It does not use an extra clearfix variant and so on...

I guess px are used more widely, because if you get a design from an agency it's most likely optimized for special px widths. Especially the inner paddings and fonts.